# How to config IIS Rewrite

Tags: php, angularjs, iis, routes, url-rewriting

My project using php and angular, it is hosted in IIS. I turn on `html5Mode` in angular, that mean I can use route like `localhost/home` instead of `locahost/#/home`.

My problem is when I copy & pass the url (ex: `http://localhost/home`) to another tab or browser, IIS return the error

`Requested URL  http://localhost/home/`

`Physical Path  <physical link>\link\`

I want using angular route (not `ui-router`) to handle all route in my application. How can I config the `URL Rewrite` to make it understand all routes just need point to the `home`?

My route of project is `index.html`. It's a normal `html` file.

In Asp.net MVC, I config that route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Renewal SPA",
                url: "{*catchall}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

How to do the same with `php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should config IIS rewrites in your config file (or in IIS) like this:

```
<system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules> 
  <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />                                 
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
  </rule>
  </rules>
 </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

> Be sure that URL Rewrite installed on your IIS (download it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7435)).

See this article:
[Configure your server to work with html5Mode](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)